# Hair Making Question

Tags: hair

I'm trying to create a hair object and while this might sound alittle lazy, rather than making actual hair, is it possible to create a hair (thick like anime hair) and then duplicate it over selected faces?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Would this spiky hair be doable using particles system?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57360/would-this-spiky-hair-be-doable-using-particles-system)

Comment: Found a video on youtube detailing how to do this, just tends to be CPU intense.