# How can I create hair using particle system as if it is modelled?

Tags: particles

I'm creating a very simple character. I don't want to model hair to save time. I can do realistic hair using the particle system but it doesn't match the cartoonish style of my character. The hair needs to be modeled.

**First try:** 
I played with the thickness of the hair and made it very thick and gave it cartoonish material. It looked pretty much like what I'm looking for but some hair didn't look well and it's hard to control

**Second try:** 
I created an object that looks like a single hair. I used a particle system to instance it many times. It doesn't look great.

Is it possible to create something similar to the pictures using the particle system instead of modeling? How can I control it or What are the parameters?

[image]

[image]
**Edit:**
I used exactly the same parameters as the other question suggested but I was out of luck! The differences are my mish was made of quads instead of triangles and I used an object instead of a Bazier curve.

[image]

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yes, your answer is great

Comment: I just moved the hair model to be along the y axis instead of the z axis and I played with some other properties (not too much far from your answer) and it worked for me

Comment: Thank you for your assistance

Comment: You don't have to delete them, it helps other people find similar issues more easily. You should also upvote answers that help you, it helps the people who spend time answering, and helps other users find relevant content

Comment: Okay. I won't delete it :) BTW, I upvoted your answer as it helped me :) @DuarteFarrajotaRamos